# How to implement kafka consumer using lagom framework

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, message-queue, kafka-consumer-api, lagom

Tried different documentation but not able to implement kafka consumer api using lagom.
Followed [Message broker](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/scala/MessageBrokerApi.html) and getting **Object creation impossible, since member lagomServer: LagomServer in com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.server.LagomServerComponents is not defined** in loader class. Below is the code snippet of my loader class.

```
class ConsumerLoader extends LagomApplicationLoader {

  override def load(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication =
    new ConsumerApplication(context) with ConfigurationServiceLocatorComponents

  override def describeService = Some(readDescriptor[ConsumerService])
}

abstract class ConsumerApplication(context: LagomApplicationContext)
  extends LagomApplication(context)
    with AhcWSComponents {

  lazy val kafkaService = serviceClient.implement[ConsumerService]
}
```

Please provide me with the useful documentation link on how to implement kafka message consumer.

Answer (score 1):

I did it following way:

When Service that read and write to the topic is different services or you need just implement reader:

1. Add topic method `def topic: Topic[Envelope]` into service reader

```
trait ReaderKafkaService extends Service {
  def topic1: Topic[Envelope]

  override final def descriptor: Descriptor = {

    named("kafka-reader")
      .withTopics(
        topic("topic-name", topic1)
      )
      .withAutoAcl(true)
  }
}
```

2. Service where you what to read from kafka:

```
ConsumerService extends Service {
  override final def descriptor: Descriptor = {

    named("consumer-service")
      .withAutoAcl(true)
  }
}
```

3. Add in Loader this service:

```
lazy val kafkaService: ReaderKafkaService = serviceClient.implement[ReaderKafkaService]
```

4. Inject created service in your impl:

```
class ServiceImpl(
    kafkaService: ReaderKafkaService,
) extends ConsumerService
```

5. Subscribe to topic

```
class ServiceImpl(
    kafkaService: ReaderKafkaService,
) extends ConsumerService {

  kafkaService.topic1.subscribe
    .withGroupId("group-1")
    .atLeastOnce(
      Flow[Envelope]
        .mapAsync(1) {
          case envelope: Envelope =>
              println(s" Message from topic: $envelope") 
              Future.successful(Done)
        }
        .recover {
          case e =>
            log.error(s"Invalid message $e")
            Done
        }
    )
}
```

6. If needed add in config configuration for kafka

```
kafka {
  bootstrap.servers = "localhost:9092"
}
```

When you want to write and read from the same service:

1. Add service method:

```
trait ReaderWriterService extends Service {
  def topic1: Topic[Envelope]

  override final def descriptor: Descriptor = {

    named("kafka-reader-writer")
      .withTopics(
        topic("topic-name", topic1)
      )
      .withAutoAcl(true)
  }
}
```

2. Service impl:

```
class ServiceImpl(
    kafkaService: ReaderWriterService,
) extends ReaderWriterService {

  kafkaService.topic1.subscribe
    .withGroupId("group-1")
    .atLeastOnce(
      Flow[Envelope]
        .mapAsync(1) {
          case envelope: String =>
              println(s" Message from topic: $envelope") 
              Future.successful(Done)
        }
        .recover {
          case e =>
            log.error(s"Invalid message $e")
            Done
        }
    )

  override def topic1(): Topic[String] =
    TopicProducer.singleStreamWithOffset { fromOffset =>
      persistentEntityRegistry
        .eventStream(Event.Tag, fromOffset)
        .map(ev => ("Hi world", ev.offset))
    }
}
```

3. In the loader you need to extend  `with LagomKafkaComponents` and add this as service  `lazy val kafka: ProfileService = serviceClient.implement[ProfileService]`

```
abstract class Application(context: LagomApplicationContext)
  extends LagomApplication(context)
    with CassandraPersistenceComponents
    with LagomKafkaComponents
    with AhcWSComponents {

  override lazy val lagomServer = serverFor[ReaderWriterService](wire[ServiceImpl])

  lazy val kafka: ReaderWriterService = serviceClient.implement[ReaderWriterService]

  persistentEntityRegistry.register(wire[PersistentEntity])
}
```

Comment: Once we extend our impl with KafkaService then we have to provide implementation for topic method.
Did as you mentioned and now I am getting error Class 'ServiceImpl' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member
Below is the code snippet of impl class 

```class ServiceImpl(kafkaService: ConsumerService) extends ConsumerService{
  kafkaService.greetingsTopic.subscribe.atLeastOnce(Flow.fromFunction(displayMessage))

  def displayMessage( msg : String): Done = {
    println(s"Message :::::::::::  $msg")
    Done.getInstance
  }
}```

Comment: Create just KafkaService and inject it instead of ConsumerService

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at [the documentation](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/scala/MessageBrokerApi.html) and [the lagom github repository](https://github.com/lagom/lagom.github.io/tree/6adb20501aceed03481f57d58aa8a8cbfda8f4ee/src/docs/current/scala/resources/guide/broker/code/docs/scaladsl/mb). AnotherServiceImpl contains logic of Kafka consumer. The appropriate loader is defined in AnotherServiceSpec.scala in AnotherApplication class.